# Site not reach after changing URL and not reach Wp-admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My site not reach after changing URL from IP address to domain name. We successfully change from setting general (site URL and home URL) after changing session out cant login again browser said (Site not reach).

Also WP-Admin not reach after changing URL.

We also revert from phpMyAdmin (Database) wp-option in to my IP address. Site is working fine when we set IP address. But when we set domain name site cant reach.

please tell me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```